# Write file in UTF-8 mode using Perl

Tags: perl

I need to write a file with UTF-8 mode in Perl. How do i create that?

Can anyone help in this case?

I'm trying like this, Find my below code,

```
use utf8;
use open ':encoding(utf8)'; 
binmode(FH, ":utf32");

open(FH, ">test11.txt"); 
print FH "something Çirçös";
```

It's creating a file with UTF-8 Format. But i need to make sure whether that is happening from this script. Because if i'm writing a file without using utf8 encode also, File content is automatically taking as UTF-8 format.

Comment: Makes no sense to binmode a glob which doesn't have an open handle.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want

```
use utf8;                       # Source code is encoded using UTF-8.

open(my $FH, ">:encoding(utf-8)", "test11.txt")
    or die $!;

print $FH "something Çirçös";
```

or

```
use utf8;                       # Source code is encoded using UTF-8.
use open ':encoding(utf-8)';    # Sets the default encoding for handles opened in scope.

open(my $FH, ">", "test11.txt")
    or die $!;

print $FH "something Çirçös";
```

Notes:

- The encoding you want is `utf-8` (case-insensitive), not `utf8` (a Perl-specific encoding).
- Don't use global vars; use lexical (`my`) vars.
- If you leave off the instruction to encode, you might get lucky and get the right output (along with a "wide character" warning). Don't count on this. You won't always be lucky.

  ```
  # Unlucky.
  $ perl -we'use utf8; print "é"' | od -t x1
  0000000 e9
  0000001

  # Lucky.
  $ perl -we'use utf8; print "é♡"' | od -t x1
  Wide character in print at -e line 1.
  0000000 c3 a9 e2 99 a1
  0000005

  # Correct.
  $ perl -we'use utf8; binmode STDOUT, ":encoding(utf-8)"; print "é♡"' | od -t x1
  0000000 c3 a9 e2 99 a1
  0000005
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.